# Select unrelated ids on relate / lookup table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, set-operations

I have seen various examples for this, but I can't find a definitive example of how to return all rows from `table_A` that are not related to a row in `table_B` using relate `table_A_B` without a given value for either `table_A.id` or `table_B.id`.  The closest matchs I can find to this are:

1. Get a list of `A` not related to one or more rows in `B` but without knowing which value in B is the issue.
2. Get a list of `A` not related to given `B`.
3. Get list of `A` with comma-separated field of unrelated `B` (not sure I saw that, but it seemed like one example could expand as such).
4. A list of `A`s and `B`s not related to each other but no indication of which is not related to the other.

I can also get a list of all potential `A_B` tuples with:

```
SELECT A.id, B.id  FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.id <> B.id
```

And I could hypothetically use one of the `EXCEPT` workarounds (I think) against the relate table, but all attempts were unsuccessful and I imagine that once there are millions of potential combinations returned by that join it will be much less efficient anyway.

So given the table values:

```
A
id | name
 1 | X
 2 | y
 3 | z


B
id | name
 7 | e
 8 | f
 9 | g

A_B
id | a_id | b_id
 1 |    1 |    7
 2 |    1 |    8
 3 |    1 |    9
 1 |    2 |    7
 2 |    2 |    8
 1 |    3 |    7
```

Is there a query that would return:
     A | B 
     2 | 9
     3 | 8
     3 | 9

Or even better:

```
 A | B 
 y | g
 z | f
 z | g
```

Or is this asking for trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a cross join between A and B to get all possible pairs.  Then do a left join to the relation table and choose where there is no match:

```
select driver.aID, driver.bID
from (select a.id as aID, b.id as bID
      from table_A A cross join table_B B
     ) driver left outer join
     table_A_B ab
     on ab.aID = driver.aID and ab.bID = bID
where ab.aID is null
```

This works, assuming that the ids are never NULL.

I haven't tested the SQL so it might have syntax errors.

This version gets you the names:

```
select driver.aName, driver.bName
from (select a.id as aID, b.id as bID, a.name as aName, b.name as Bname
      from table_A A cross join table_B B
     ) driver left outer join
     table_A_B ab
     on ab.aID = driver.aID and ab.bID = bID
where ab.aID is null
```

Comment: I tried using the `INNER JOIN A.id <> B.id` to get the full list of potentials but it was failing at every turn.  Glad I had the right idea logically and that you knew how to take it home. Thanks!